# maas node deployment failed

Tags: maas

MaaS = ubuntu 15
Nodes = ubuntu 14

Using maas: 1.7.6+bzr3376-0ubuntu2~15.04.1
http://pastebin.com/4nCxtMg2

The node fails after a PXE boot curtain install request. Cloud init info from node:
http://pastebin.com/TPJaNmHT

syslog:
http://pastebin.com/JjMu4kVV

Specifics that I do have concern over

cloud init:
    Aug 26 10:11:52 ubuntu pollinate[881]: ERROR: Network communication failed [60]\n10:11:52.438763 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

syslog:

```
Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   22.400525] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   22.400806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   23.155507] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (784) terminated with status 1
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   23.822992] init: cloud-init main process (745) terminated with status 1
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   23.853475] init: failsafe main process (918) killed by TERM signal
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
    Aug 26 10:11:52 high-pin kernel: [   23.931456] type=1400 audit(1440583912.734:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1110 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Other Systlog message:

```
Aug 26 10:12:03 high-pin kernel: [   34.574589] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Aug 26 10:17:03 high-pin kernel: [  333.909164]  connection1:0: ping timeout of 5 secs expired, recv timeout 5, last rx 4294973356, last ping 4294974608, now 4294975860
Aug 26 10:17:03 high-pin kernel: [  333.909283]  connection1:0: detected conn error (1011)
Aug 26 10:17:03 high-pin iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1011 - ISCSI_ERR_CONN_FAILED: iSCSI connection failed) state (3)
Aug 26 10:17:12 high-pin CRON[1654]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 26 10:17:12 high-pin iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (1 attempts)
Aug 26 10:28:20 high-pin kernel: [ 1010.724344]  connection1:0: ping timeout of 5 secs expired, recv timeout 5, last rx 4295142724, last ping 4295143976, now 4295145228
Aug 26 10:28:20 high-pin kernel: [ 1010.724413]  connection1:0: detected conn error (1011)
Aug 26 10:28:20 high-pin iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1011 - ISCSI_ERR_CONN_FAILED: iSCSI connection failed) state (3)
Aug 26 10:28:40 high-pin iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (2 attempts)
Aug 26 10:33:26 high-pin kernel: [ 1315.964125]  connection1:0: ping timeout of 5 secs expired, recv timeout 5, last rx 4295219108, last ping 4295220360, now 4295221612
Aug 26 10:33:26 high-pin kernel: [ 1315.964194]  connection1:0: detected conn error (1011)
Aug 26 10:33:26 high-pin iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1011 - ISCSI_ERR_CONN_FAILED: iSCSI connection failed) state (3)
Aug 26 10:33:29 high-pin iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (1 attempts)
```

looking up the hostname via "nslookup high-pin" does not work, however "nslookup high-pin.maas" does. the resolv.conf does not contain a search domain. Is this normal for a curtain install?

nslookup, apt-get upgrade, apt-get update, ping, all work and routing.

Maas event log:

http://pastebin.com/w9dQs6Ws

This node was working 1 day ago, the only thing I can think of is possibly the maas log might help? It did update to a new version of the image via a sync.

MaaS log:

http://pastebin.com/w8wt4d1j

Any ideas on how to chase down what I might need to tweak to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was just a mirror issue. changing from archive.ubuntu.com to one of the mirrors listed here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors
ended up working.