# maas fails in deploying a node

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I have a physical server with ubunut 14.04 and maas 1.8.2 on it with access to Internet. There is a node connected to maas server through a switch. Common configurations for maas's NICs has been taken care of. 
When I choose a node with "New" status in maas gui and hit deployment, it seems that everything goes well until I can see at the node's screen that it is trying to get to some "http://archive.ubuntu..." of no avail. That is it, after quite a long time being stuck in this situation eventually node's status on maas gui changes to "deployment failed". It is strange because I'm pretty sure that maas has been appropriately configured to provide Internet access for nodes through private network. Anyone out there to kindly instruct me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seemed to be a problem with the default mirror "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" that is set in setting tab of maas gui (As was pointed out in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665973/maas-node-deployment-failed/)). When I changed it to a different mirror address it got to internet but it was too slow that maas gui displayed "failed commissioning" under node's status. Selecting other mirrors was of no use. So I thought maybe it had something to do with my Internet connection and tested it by downloading a relatively large file from the same domain I had used as a mirror address and to my amazement it went quite fast!
I'm really puzzled and dont know what to do next. Please help. Thank you in advance.